# Casting to pointer warning

Tags: c, embedded

I defined variables display_address, version, serial_no[] as uint8_t and forwarded them to function, that variables need to be pointers so I casted it (uint8_t *)variable, and after that I'm getting a warnings

> warning: cast to 'uint8_t *' (aka 'unsigned char *') from smaller
>   integer type uint8_t (aka 'unsigned char')

What's the problem, and why this wont work?

Here is function which I'm forwarding parameters

```
void write_to_flash (void)    {                     
BYTE i;

    iap_copy_to_flash((uint8_t *)display_address, OFFSET_ADDRESS, 1); //warning here
    delay_1_ms();
    iap_copy_to_flash((uint8_t *)version, OFFSET_VERSION, 1); //warning here
    delay_1_ms();
    for (i=0;i<8;i++)     {
        iap_copy_to_flash((uint8_t *)serial_no[i], OFFSET_VERSION+i, 1); //warning here
        delay_1_ms();
        }
    }
```

and iap_copy_to_flash parameters description

```
void iap_copy_to_flash (uint8_t* buff, uint32_t flash_addr, uint32_t num_bytes)
```

Comment: just watch them as variables which need to be saved to some sector on flash memory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are converting a integer to a pointer, that means that you pass the actual value in `display_address` as the pointer location. This is 99% of the time a bad idea™ unless it's a round-robin cast of some description but then I suggest fixing the intermediate storage type instead.

Instead you should use the `&` operator to take the address of the variable:

```
void write_to_flash (void)    {                     
BYTE i;

iap_copy_to_flash(&display_address, OFFSET_ADDRESS, 1); 
delay_1_ms();
iap_copy_to_flash(&version, OFFSET_VERSION, 1); 
delay_1_ms();
for (i=0;i<8;i++)     {
    iap_copy_to_flash(&serial_no[i], OFFSET_VERSION+i, 1); 
    delay_1_ms();
    }
}
```